# how can I use mongoid to find like this

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

for some reason I must find recods  like this:

```
Collection.or([
  {:one_id => index_id_arr[0], :two_id.in => samp_id_ary[0]},
  {:one_id => index_id_arr[1], :two_id.in => samp_id_ary[1]},
  {:one_id => index_id_arr[2], :two_id.in => samp_id_ary[2]}
])
```

the `index_id_arr` and the `samp_id_ary` has the same length but not sure the length of them

How can I get the right collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collection.or` is just looking for an array of conditions so you just have to build that array. You know that `index_id_arr` and `samp_id_ary` have the same size so you can do things like this:

```
Collect.or(
  index_id_arr.zip(samp_id_ary).map { |one, two| { :one_id => one, :two_id.in => two } }
)
```